# how to replace content from ({{}}) Special character in php

Tags: php

I Have a Paragraph that contains some content and also values inside of {{0001ABC}} I want to replace {{0001ABC}} with some content for example code Found.

```
preg_replace('/{{"([^\\"]+)"}}/', "Code found", "Hello {{0001ABC}}");
```

The result should look like this

```
  Hello Code found
```

Comment: guys anyone knows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex pattern is incorrect.  Here is a version which should work:

```
\{\{[^{}]+\}\}
```

This will match two opening curly braces, followed by one or more characters which are not curly braces, followed by two closing curly braces.  Keep in mind that `{` and `}` are regex *metacharacters*, have a special meaning, and therefore need escaping if we want them to mean literal characters.

Your updated script:

```
$input = "Hello {{0001ABC}}";
$output = preg_replace("/\{\{[^{}]+\}\}/", "Code found", "Hello {{0001ABC}}");
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
Hello Code found
```